# Cmake macro for adding autotools-built git submodule to cmake project

Tags: git, cmake, autotools

Consider a large project (the parent project, or `"cmake-project"`) that uses git and git submodules. Some submodules are third-party and do not use cmake, but use GNU autotools.

The question is: what is a simple way to incorporate such autotools based libraries into a cmake project?

Of course it is possible to fork such repository and add cmake support yourself,
but that is often a lot of work and not always feasible.
Instead, I wish to simply use those third-party projects as-is as a submodule.

A git submodule that uses cmake itself requires the following line in the `CMakeLists.txt` of the parent project:

```
add_subdirectory( cmake-submodule )
```

For completeness, let me add the additional requirements for this case.

1. Passing `--recursive` is necessary to check out the submodule, when cloning the parent project:
   `git clone --recursive <URL-to-project>/cmake-project.git`
2. If the above was forgotten, or when a new submodule was added (by someone else), the following command is necessary to get the submodule(s):
   `git submodule update --init --recursive`
3. Submodules checked out like that are in a detached-`HEAD` state; which makes it not practical to work on them (do commits). If you want to see the whole project, including its sub directories (submodules) as "one big happy project" that you can hack away at then each submodule must be associated with a branch first:
   `git checkout master`
   After which you might want to do a `git pull --ff-only` to get the 'real' (most up to date) content of the submodule / subdirectory.

After the above, when making changes to a submodule, one can simply commit and when the whole project is in a consistent state, add the submodules to the parent project, commit that too and push everything:

```
# In each submodule:
git commit -a -m 'It works.'
```

And then,

```
make test # Success!
git commit -a -m 'Bring parent project up to date with submodules.'
git push # Automatically pushes all submodules because you already did a
         # git config push.recurseSubmodules on-demand, right?
```

What I'd like is that when I have a submodule that uses autotools instead of cmake that things are almost as simple, namely:

```
add_autotools_submodule( autotools-project ) # As opposed to add_subdirectory.
```

Could replace `submodule` with `directory`, but I wanted to stress that this will have git submodule support: we are assuming that this subdirectory is both, a git submodule, and built with GNU autotools.

Now you're going to say: but you need to pass configuration arguments and all-what-not. However, just like a cmake based submodule has all configure and build information stored in the project itself, so should a autotools built project. We can still clone this project and add all the needed information to it, somehow. This is not much work (as opposed to adding cmake support). I already did this for autotools projects that use autotools submodules. These submodules contain a [configure.m4](https://github.com/CarloWood/ai-utils/blob/master/configure.m4) file. Putting that information in the submodule (as opposed to, in this case, the `configure.ac` of every project that uses it!) avoids duplication and makes maintenance a lot easier.

`add_autotools_submodule` should use such file if it exists, and otherwise use sane defaults.

Before the submodule is downloaded this file is not available of course; obviously it does not contain any "download" information. We do not need to download anything; we're using git for that.

I have already used `ExternalProject_add` once before, for a submodule that uses autotools. The required amount of work was HUGE. You can see it in action here:

https://github.com/CarloWood/evio/blob/f8f7511ac39ea8ad1107cf62d70c71a72332cf95/protocol/CMakeLists.txt

What I'd like is to condense this into something general that can be used as a single `add_autotools_submodule` macro.

It is my hope that eventually we can arrive at something that many people can use, who also use cmake, git and need to incorporate third-party autotools libraries into their project.

Comment: look for [hunter](https://docs.hunter.sh/en/latest/creating-new/create/autotools.html)

Comment: I have been looking into hunter since you mentioned it and I don't think I want to use it: 1) I get no replies from Ruslan, 2) his documentation is hard to navigate (I can't find things), 3) it seems that this a method to cache binary (compiled) packages based on the hash of what is probably determining the ABI of said packages, but it is not meant to do what I want. Even though it seems to support certain packages that are build with autotools it doesn't have support for arbitrary packages and I can't figure out how to add my own. More over the result would be some weird binary caching...